# iOS - View that handle taps, but let swipes go through to the superview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have an app with quite a complex UI, there's a big `UIView` called the cover with a `UITableView` underneath it. The `tableView` is configured with a `tableHeaderView` of the same height as the cover. As the `tableView` scrolls up, the cover moves up the screen (with various fancy animations) using a `UIScrollViewDelegate`. To allow users to scroll the `tableView` by swiping the cover, I've overridden the `- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method to always return `false`.

I've now added some `UIButton` views to the cover. I've managed to make them respond to taps by changing the way I've overriden the `pointInside` method like this:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
BOOL isInside = [_directionsButton pointInside:[_directionsButton convertPoint:point fromView:self] withEvent:event];
return isInside;
}
```

The only problem now is that if you start a swipe gesture on the button, it's caught by the button and the `tableView` doesn't scroll. I want to be able to ignore swipe gestures on the button (so really let them pass to the view below).

Normally, I would just make the cover view the `tableHeaderView`, which seems to handle this kind of behaviour really well. However, I can't do this here, due to some unique animations done on the cover as the table scrolls.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried identifying the Gestures using Gesture Recognisers and doing action method that is to be called when the specified gesture is detected?

Please check this [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Identifying_Gestures_using_iOS_7_Gesture_Recognizers). This may help you for that.

Comment: That's a start, but I'm really looking for a solution so that when a swipe gesture is detected as starting on a UIButton it passes the whole touch to it's superview (which in turn lets it pass through to the view below). I'm confident I could detect swipes on the button, but then how to ignore them?

Comment: When processing those swipes, figure out where the swipe originated, and whether that point is in the frame of where you used to have the UIView.